# R's read.table equivalent in Python

Tags: python, r, read.table

I'm trying to move some of my processing work from R to Python.  In R, I use read.table() to read REALLY messy CSV files and it automagically splits the records in the correct format.  E.g.

```
391788,"HP Deskjet 3050 scanner always seems to break","<p>I'm running a Windows 7 64 blah blah blah........ake this work permanently?</p>

<p>Update: It might have something to do with my computer. It seems to work much better on another computer, windows 7 laptop. Not sure exactly what the deal is, but I'm still looking into it...</p>
","windows-7 printer hp"
```

is correctly separated into 4 columns.  1 record can be split over many lines and there are commas all over the place.  In R I just do:

```
read.table(infile, header = FALSE, nrows=chunksize, sep=",", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Is there something in Python that can do this equally well?

Thanks!

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604564/create-pandas-dataframe-from-a-string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use csv module.

```
from csv import reader
csv_reader = reader(open("C:/text.txt","r"), quotechar="\"")

for row in csv_reader:
    print row

['391788', 'HP Deskjet 3050 scanner always seems to break', "<p>I'm running a Windows 7 64 blah blah blah........ake this work permanently?</p>\n\n<p>Update: It might have something to do with my computer. It seems to work much better on another computer, windows 7 laptop. Not sure exactly what the deal is, but I'm still looking into it...</p>\n", 'windows-7 printer hp']
```

length of output = 4

Comment: But this just returns strings. It doesn't infer the type of each column the way that read.table does.

Answer (score 3):

The `pandas` module also offers many R-like functions and data structures, including `read_csv`. The advantage here is that the data will be read in as a pandas `DataFrame`, which is a little easier to manaipulate than a standard python list or dict (especially if you're accustomed to R). Here is an example:

```
>>> from pandas import read_csv
>>> ugly = read_csv("ugly.csv",header=None)
>>> ugly
        0                                              1  \
0  391788  HP Deskjet 3050 scanner always seems to break   

                                                   2                     3  
0  <p>I'm running a Windows 7 64 blah blah blah.....  windows-7 printer hp
```