# Create Pandas DataFrame from a string

Tags: python, string, pandas, csv, csv-import

In order to test some functionality I would like to create a `DataFrame` from a string. Let's say my test data looks like:

```
TESTDATA="""col1;col2;col3
1;4.4;99
2;4.5;200
3;4.7;65
4;3.2;140
"""
```

What is the simplest way to read that data into a Pandas `DataFrame`?

Answer (score 818, accepted):

A simple way to do this is to use [`StringIO.StringIO` (python2)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.StringIO) or [`io.StringIO` (python3)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) and pass that to the [`pandas.read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) function. E.g:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3: 
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd

TESTDATA = StringIO("""col1;col2;col3
    1;4.4;99
    2;4.5;200
    3;4.7;65
    4;3.2;140
    """)

df = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, sep=";")
```

Comment: FYI - `pd.read_table()` is an equivalent function, just slightly better nomenclature: `df = pd.read_table(TESTDATA, sep=";")`.

Comment: @AntonvBR Noted that one could use `pandas.compat.StringIO`. That way we don't have to import `StringIO` separately. However the `pandas.compat` package is considered private according to http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html?highlight=compat so leaving the answer as is for now.

Comment: Time to sort out which import: [Should we use pandas.compat.StringIO or Python 2/3 StringIO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50283292/should-we-use-pandas-compat-stringio-or-python-2-3-stringio)

Comment: If you create TESTDATA with `df.to_csv(TESTDATA)`, use `TESTDATA.seek(0)`

Comment: I receive 'Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 26, saw 12\n',)

Comment: This is what I needed to do when uploading CSV files in colab. In order to make a dataframe out of the CSV, I used this method

Comment: @gdm The "Expected fields error" is usually due to inconsistent number of fields in each row, or wrong sep/delimiter.

Comment: @Asclepius the suggestion to use `pandas.compat` only works for versions before pandas 0.25, but will now raise ImportError.

Answer (score 62):

**In one line, but first import `io`**

```
import pandas as pd
import io   

TESTDATA="""col1;col2;col3
1;4.4;99
2;4.5;200
3;4.7;65
4;3.2;140
"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(TESTDATA), sep=";")
print(df)
```

Comment: What is the difference between this and the accepted answer? Except you move io operation to read_csv, which makes no difference... Please always check if similar answer is not posted already, redundancy is unnecessary.

Comment: I like this answer because it is explained with one example in one line.

Answer (score 59):

**Split Method**

```
data = input_string
df = pd.DataFrame([x.split(';') for x in data.split('\n')])
print(df)
```

Comment: If you want the first line to be used for column names, change the 2nd line to this: `df = pd.DataFrame([x.split(';') for x in data.split('\n')[1:]], columns=[x for x in data.split('\n')[0].split(';')])`

Comment: This is wrong, since on CSV files the newline (\n) character can be part of a field.

Comment: This is not very robust, and most people would be better with the accepted answer. There is a very partial list of things that can go wrong with this at http://thomasburette.com/blog/2014/05/25/so-you-want-to-write-your-own-CSV-code/

Comment: This is a weak and unnecessary approach. This circumvents the built-in `pd.read_csv()` call which handles any CSV and has been battle-tested in favor of a naive couple of string splits that don't handle quoting and are liable to fail in many cases. It's also more verbose. Please use the CSV parser Pandas kindly gives you!

Answer (score 26):

A quick and easy solution for interactive work is to copy-and-paste the text by loading the data from the clipboard.

Select the content of the string with your mouse:

[image: Copy data for pasting into a Pandas dataframe]

In the Python shell use [`read_clipboard()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_clipboard.html)

```
>>> pd.read_clipboard()
  col1;col2;col3
0       1;4.4;99
1      2;4.5;200
2       3;4.7;65
3      4;3.2;140
```

Use the appropriate separator:

```
>>> pd.read_clipboard(sep=';')
   col1  col2  col3
0     1   4.4    99
1     2   4.5   200
2     3   4.7    65
3     4   3.2   140

>>> df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=';') # save to dataframe
```

Comment: Not good for reproducibility, but otherwise a pretty neat solution!

Answer (score 9):

This answer applies when a string is manually entered, not when it's read from somewhere.

A traditional variable-width CSV is unreadable for storing data as a string variable. Especially for use inside a `.py` file, consider fixed-width pipe-separated data instead. Various IDEs and editors may have a plugin to format pipe-separated text into a neat table.

### Using [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Store the following in a utility module, e.g. `util/pandas.py`. An example is included in the function's docstring.

```py
import io
import re

import pandas as pd


def read_psv(str_input: str, **kwargs) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Read a Pandas object from a pipe-separated table contained within a string.

    Input example:
        | int_score | ext_score | eligible |
        |           | 701       | True     |
        | 221.3     | 0         | False    |
        |           | 576       | True     |
        | 300       | 600       | True     |

    The leading and trailing pipes are optional, but if one is present,
    so must be the other.

    `kwargs` are passed to `read_csv`. They must not include `sep`.

    In PyCharm, the "Pipe Table Formatter" plugin has a "Format" feature that can 
    be used to neatly format a table.

    Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46471952/
    """

    substitutions = [
        ('^ *', ''),  # Remove leading spaces
        (' *$', ''),  # Remove trailing spaces
        (r' *\| *', '|'),  # Remove spaces between columns
    ]
    if all(line.lstrip().startswith('|') and line.rstrip().endswith('|') for line in str_input.strip().split('\n')):
        substitutions.extend([
            (r'^\|', ''),  # Remove redundant leading delimiter
            (r'\|$', ''),  # Remove redundant trailing delimiter
        ])
    for pattern, replacement in substitutions:
        str_input = re.sub(pattern, replacement, str_input, flags=re.MULTILINE)
    return pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(str_input), sep='|', **kwargs)
```

### Non-working alternatives

The code below doesn't work properly because it adds an empty column on both the left and right sides.

```py
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(df_str), sep=r'\s*\|\s*', engine='python')
```

As for `read_fwf`, it [doesn't actually use](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59757478/) so many of the optional kwargs that `read_csv` accepts and uses. As such, it shouldn't be used at all for pipe-separated data.

Comment: I found (by trial&error) that `read_fwf` takes more of `read_csv`s arguments than is documented, but it's true that [some have no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59757478/974555).

Answer (score 4):

Object: Take string make dataframe.

### Solution

```py
def str2frame(estr, sep = ',', lineterm = '\n', set_header = True):
    dat = [x.split(sep) for x in estr.strip(lineterm).split(lineterm)]
    df = pd.DataFrame(dat)
    if set_header:
        df = df.T.set_index(0, drop = True).T # flip, set ix, flip back
    return df
```

### Example

```py
estr = """
sym,date,strike,genus
APPLE,20MAY20,50.0,Malus
ORANGE,22JUL20,50.0,Rutaceae
"""

df = str2frame(estr)
```

```py
print(df)
0     sym     date strike     genus
1   APPLE  20MAY20   50.0     Malus
2  ORANGE  22JUL20   50.0  Rutaceae
```

Comment: Please use descriptive variable names and not estr, dat, cdf.

Comment: The style is intentional; feel free to copy this answer and use your own notation.

Comment: [Same remark as this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54812940/6243352). Please don't reinvent the wheel, just use `pd.read_csv()`.

Comment: If you have one, a better solution depending only on pandas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Emample:**

```
text = [ ['This is the NLP TASKS ARTICLE written by Anjum**'] ,['IN this article I”ll be explaining various DATA-CLEANING techniques '], ['So stay tuned for FURther More && '],['Nah I dont think he goes to usf ; he lives around']]
df = pd.DataFrame({'text':text})
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question. OP wants to read a CSV from a string, completely missing here.

Comment: @ggorlen. First see the question: "Create Pandas DataFrame from a string" and then see my answer. lol

Comment: Sorry, I did that and don't see what you mean. There's no CSV string in your answer. You've hardcoded a list, completely bypassing a conversion step that all of the other answers here address. The question has nothing to do with converting lists to dataframes. Even if you were going to hardcode lists, this is a poor solution because it adds extra single-element inner list wrappers on each of the strings for no apparent reason, making the `text` column an object rather than a string datatype.