# pandas randomly reads one NaN?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas, nan

I have a series of .csv files that I'm reading with pandas.read_csv. From a bunch of columns, I only read 2, (the 2nd and 15th columns).

```
   datafiles = glob.glob(mypath)
   for dfile in datafiles:
        data = pd.read_csv(dfile,header=6,usecols=['Reading','Value'])
```

the CSV looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2348.png), with a few lines of header at the top. Every once in a while pandas reads one of these numbers off as a NaN. Excel has no trouble reading these values, and visually inspecting the file I don't see what causes the problem. Specifically in this case, the row indexed as 265 in this file, 263 in the data frame, the 'Value' column reads a NaN when it should be ~27.4.

```
    >>>data['Value'][264]
    nan
```

This problem is consistent doesn't change with the number of files I read. In many of the files, this problem is not present. In the rest, it will only read one random number as a NaN, in either one of the columns. I've tried changing from the automatic float64 to np.float128 using dtype, but this doesn't fix it. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Update: A grep search shows that the newline character is \M with only 4 exceptions--lines at the beginning of every file before the header.  On further inspection, this specific point [264] is treated differently in the failing files: In 5/12 files, it's fine. In 2/12 files it's read out as 27.0, in 3/12 it's read out as nan, and in 2/12 files it's read out as 2.0. One of the files (one that reads out a 27.0) is available for [download here](http://www.filedropper.com/t3d04)

Comment: Is it possible the file has different newline characters on some rows? Is the file in UTF-8-BOM format? Try switching it to just UTF-8 using notepad++

Comment: Can you upload one of the problematic CSVs somewhere?

Comment: @CharlieHaley Check the Update. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you randomly have [null characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) throughout your csv files, and they are causing the problem.  What you need to do to fix this is replace `\0` with nothing.

Here's an example of how to do so.  The imports are [because of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604564/how-to-create-a-pandas-dataframe-from-string) loading from a string instead of from a file.

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO

datafiles = glob.glob(mypath)
for dfile in datafiles:
    st=''
    with open(dfile,'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.replace('\0','')
            st += line
    data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(st),header=6,usecols=['Reading','Value'])
```

It would be cool if pandas had a function to do this by default when you load data into the DataFrame, but it appears that there is no function like that as of now.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much. I actually just found the null characters myself, but I was looking for a bash command line  to remove them, but this will work, too!