# Want to import, extracted Salesforce report content into pandas and then save it

Tags: python, csv, pandas, salesforce

Hi I connected to the salesforce using simple_salesforce module and targeted it to the report i wanted to extract. At this moment I have the desired data in csv comma seperated format and when I write
`d.content` it shows the data in comma separated but I want to have the same data in pandas dataframe.

```
d = session.get("https://nax.salesforce.com/xxxxxxxxxx?export=1&enc=UTF-8&xf=csv".format('xxxxxxxxxx'), headers=sf.headers, cookies={'sid': sf.session_id})
```

then

```
in[22]: d.content

out[22]: "whole comma seperated data"
```

I want the above data to be in pandas or saved in csv

when I write:

```
pd.DataFrame(d)
```

it gives an error out as

```
PandasError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

Please tell me how can I take it further to save the following data in either csv or insert in pandas to save it further.

Comment: Is `d.content` a string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a Pandas DataFrame from String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604564/how-to-create-a-pandas-dataframe-from-string)

Comment: no it is not as the data was taken out from sfdc report and do not exist in any csv file yet

Comment: 'd.content' is to check content in the fetched data from Salesforce

Comment: in[55]: type(d.content) 
Out[55]: bytes

Comment: I guess the data is in `d.text`?

Comment: so if you see the code
`d = session.get("https://nax.salesforce.com/xxxxxxxxxx?export=1&enc=UTF-8&xf=csv".format('xxxxxxxxxx'), headers=sf.headers, cookies={'sid': sf.session_id})`

there is a link of salesforce, which is ""https://nax.salesforce.com/xxxxxxxxxx"

this is a report which was fetched using the above code and now it lies in 'd' I want this to be saved in csv or to put into pandas dataframe

Comment: can you show what `d.text` returns?

Comment: you are right. `d.text` gave the right output

Comment: See here for documentation: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Comment: '"Party","Account Name","Alias Name","Account ID","Account Classification"\n"123456","XYZ Inc.","株式会社XYZ", 

and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data returned by the server is contained in the `text` attribute of the response: `d.text` (see documentation [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content)).

You can then use the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604564/how-to-create-a-pandas-dataframe-from-string) to create the dataframe from a string:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
pd.DataFrame.from_csv(StringIO(d.text))
```

Comment: Yes, it worked very well. Thank you for your help and time.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is more detailed than you need but as someone who searched all over for a full answer for how to download salesforce reports to excel using python I wanted to share my answer:

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
import pandas as pd
import requests
import io

# login info must be a string in "quotes" 
sf = Salesforce(username= # "UserName"
                ,password= # "Password" 
                ,security_token= # "Security Token" (can be reset in your settings in salesforce and will be sent via email)
                )

sid=sf.session_id
print ("get sid "+ sf.session_id)


#ReportID can be found when you open the report in the browser address bar as follows: https://instance.salesforce.com/[Alphanumeric ReportID]
ReportID=  #Alphanumeric Report ID as string in "quotes"

response = requests.get("https://instance.salesforce.com/"+ReportID+"?export=1&enc=UTF-8&xf=csv",
                  headers = sf.headers, cookies = {'sid' : sid})

df=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(response.text))
df=df[:-5] #takes out the confidential information warning and copywrite info

#if your first column is a number field instead of string (text) field you will need the next line(Delete the '#')
#df=df.astype({"[first column name]":'float'})


writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Salesforce Output.xlsx') #this will write the file to the same folder where this program is kept
df.to_excel(writer,index=False,header=True)

writer.save()
```

I made the comments very simple so that people who do not regularly use python or beginners can learn from my experience.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thanks for the well-commented answer. :)