# python - converting unicode in list to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unicode

I am using an API to get some data. The data returned is in Unicode (not a dictionary / json object).

```
# get data
data = []
for urls in api_call_list:
    data.append(requests.get(urls))
```

the data looks like this:

```
>>> data[0].text
u'Country;Celebrity;Song Volume;CPP;Index\r\nus;Taylor Swift;33100;0.83;0.20\r\n'

>>> data[1].text
u'Country;Celebrity;Song Volume;CPP;Index\r\nus;Rihanna;28100;0.76;0.33\r\n'
```

I want to put this in a `DataFrame` with Country, Celebrity, Song, Volume, CPP and Index as column names.

First I tried to split it on `\r\n` like this:

```
x = [i.text.split('\r\n') for i in data]
```

and got:

```
[[u'Country;Celebrity;Song Volume;CPP;Index',
  u'us;Taylor Swift;33100;0.83;0.20',
  u''],
 [u'Country;Celebrity;Song Volume;CPP;Index',
  u'us;Rihanna;28100;0.76;0.33',
  u'']]
```

Not sure where to go from here . . .

Comment: What should be the final result, with key:value as dict then to dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pandas.read_csv` to read *data* as a list of data frames and then concatenate them:

```
# if you use python 2 change this to // from io import BytesIO and use BytesIO instead
from io import StringIO     
import pandas as pd

pd.concat([pd.read_csv(StringIO(d), sep = ";") for d in data])
```

[image]

Since your actual data is a list of *responses*, you may need access the text firstly:

```
pd.concat([pd.read_csv(StringIO(d.text), sep = ";") for d in data])
```

---

```
data = [u'Country;Celebrity;Song Volume;CPP;Index\r\nus;Taylor Swift;33100;0.83;0.20\r\n', 
        u'Country;Celebrity;Song Volume;CPP;Index\r\nus;Rihanna;28100;0.76;0.33\r\n']
```

Comment: exactly that :) It used to be from StringIO import StringIO, see a nice import version here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604564/how-to-create-a-pandas-dataframe-from-string

Comment: It converts string object to a file like handle so that `pandas.read_csv` can read.

Comment: what about something like `pd.read_csv(String('\n'.join(data)), sep=';')`... unverified.

Comment: @piRSquared Each element in the list contains a header, so it will be better to read them separately and then concatenate.

Comment: @Psidom I missed that.  Good call then