# CSV file from string output

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have this kind of string output:

```
Gender,Age,Weight,Height
Male, 55, 82, 180
Female, 34,55,167
Female,44,67,182
Male,81,73,175
Male,44,34,87,185
```

What is the easiest way to make CSV file from this output? I tried some StringIO methods but I can't get them work in Python 3.6.0.

Comment: This output is already in a legal CSV format. Is your question specifically on how to create a file from the text?

Comment: One of possible solutions is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604564/how-to-create-a-pandas-dataframe-from-string

Comment: Looks like you need to read up on the `csv` module.

Comment: Yes my question is how to create a file from the text

Answer (score 5):

## First Approach: Use StringIO

Here is my approach, which I tested against Python 3.6:

```
import csv
from io import StringIO

my_string = """
Gender,Age,Weight,Height
Male, 55, 82, 180
Female, 34,55,167
Female,44,67,182
Male,81,73,175
Male,44,34,87,185
"""

buffer = StringIO(my_string)

reader = csv.reader(buffer, skipinitialspace=True)
with open('string2csv.csv', 'w') as out_file:
    writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    writer.writerows(reader)
```

Contents of string2csv.csv file:

```
Gender,Age,Weight,Height
Male,55,82,180
Female,34,55,167
Female,44,67,182
Male,81,73,175
Male,44,34,87,185
```

#### Notes

- Since the input string has spaces after comma (in other word, initial spaces before an entry), I am using the `skipinitialspace=True` argument to strip these spaces off.
- By using `writerows` (plural) instead of `writerow` (singular), I am able to write less code

## Second Approach: Split Lines

If you don't want to use StringIO, then we can split the lines, feed them into `csv.reader` and achieve the same result:

```
my_string = """
Gender,Age,Weight,Height
Male, 55, 82, 180
Female, 34,55,167
Female,44,67,182
Male,81,73,175
Male,44,34,87,185
"""
reader = csv.reader(my_string.splitlines(), skipinitialspace=True)
with open('string2csv.csv', 'w') as out_file:
    writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    writer.writerows(reader)
```

Comment: For those that read the posted solution, the next problem you are going to face is that `""` final new line in the end of the csv which you could remove by replacing `writer.writerows(reader)` with a for loop like this 
`for row in reader: if row == [""]: continue writer.writerow(row)`. Sorry for bad identation

Answer (score 3):

assuming you have this string in a list, why not directly write to a file

```
>>> f = file('test.csv', 'w')
>>> lines = [ 'Gender,Age,Weight,Height',
    'Male, 55, 82, 180',
    'Female, 34,55,167',
    'Female,44,67,182',
    'Male,81,73,175',
    'Male,44,34,87,185']
>>> f.write('\n'.join(lines))
>>> f.flush()
>>> f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have this kind of string output.

Let's assume that the string name is `data`.

```
import StringIO
import csv

data = """Gender,Age,Weight,Height
Male, 55, 82, 180
Female, 34,55,167
Female,44,67,182
Male,81,73,175
Male,44,34,87,185"""

f = StringIO.StringIO(data)
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')

myfile = open('output.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

for row in reader:
    print '\t'.join(row)
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: I got "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'StringIO'"

Comment: @JuhoM Maybe thats because you are using python3. instead of `import StringIO` write `from io import StringIO`

Comment: I tried it and now I got "AttributeError: type object '_io.StringIO' has no attribute 'StringIO' "

Answer (score 0):

You can used pandas and the data frame to do this :

```
df = { 'Gender' : pd.Series(['Male', 'Female', 'Female', 'Male', 'Male']), 
       'Age' : pd.Series([55, 34, 44, 81, 44]), 
      'Weight' : pd.Series([82, 55, 67, 73, 87]), 
      'Height' : pd.Series([180, 167, 182, 175, 185])}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

df.to_csv('my_file.csv', '\t')
```

Comment: Practically this is hard to do because my string output data is quite big, so it's hard to put manually values to pd.Series[ ].

Comment: Do you have a set of data ?