# Reading multiple csv files from S3 bucket with boto3

Tags: python, csv, amazon-s3, boto3

I need to read multiple csv files from S3 bucket with boto3 in python and finally combine those files in single dataframe in pandas.

I am able to read single file from following script in python

```
 s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
 bucket = s3.Bucket('test-bucket')
 for obj in bucket.objects.all():
    key = obj.key
    body = obj.get()['Body'].read()
```

Following is my path

```
 files/splittedfiles/Code-345678
```

In `Code-345678` I have multiple `csv` files which I have to read and combine it to single dataframe in pandas

Also, how do I pass a list of selected `Codes` as a list,so that it will read those folders only.  e.g.

```
files/splittedfiles/Code-345678
files/splittedfiles/Code-345679
files/splittedfiles/Code-345680
files/splittedfiles/Code-345681
files/splittedfiles/Code-345682
```

From above I need to read files under following codes only.

```
345678,345679,345682
```

How can I do it in python?

Answer (score 13):

The `boto3` API does not support reading multiple objects at once.  What you can do is retrieve all objects with a specified prefix and load each of the returned objects with a loop.  To do this you can use the `filter()` method and set the `Prefix` parameter to the prefix of the objects you want to load.  Below I've made this simple change to your code that will let you get all the objects with the prefix "files/splittedfiles/Code-345678" that you can read by looping through those objects where you can load each file into a DataFrame:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('test-bucket')
prefix_objs = bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="files/splittedfiles/Code-345678")
for obj in prefix_objs:
    key = obj.key
    body = obj.get()['Body'].read()
```

If you have multiple prefixes you are going to want to evaluate you can take the above and turn it into a function where the prefix is a parameter then combine the results together.  The function could like something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

def read_prefix_to_df(prefix):
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    bucket = s3.Bucket('test-bucket')
    prefix_objs = bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=prefix)
    prefix_df = []
    for obj in prefix_objs:
        key = obj.key
        body = obj.get()['Body'].read()
        df = pd.DataFrame(body)
        prefix_df.append(df)
    return pd.concat(prefix_df)
```

Then you can iteratively apply this function to each prefix and combine the results in the end.

Comment: `*** ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!`

Answer may be deprecated. `body` is a bytes object, which I had to convert into a utf-8 specified string encoding and then a StringIO object as shown here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47379476/how-to-convert-bytes-data-into-a-python-pandas-dataframe, but that just set the entire string as a column name with empty values.

Answer (score 13):

Modifying Answer 1 to overcome error `DataFrame constructor not properly called!`

Code:

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd
import io

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket_name')
prefix_objs = bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="folder_path/prefix")

prefix_df = []

for obj in prefix_objs:
    key = obj.key
    body = obj.get()['Body'].read()
    temp = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(body), encoding='utf8')        
    prefix_df.append(temp)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you do it like this, using "filter" instead of "all":

```
for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='files/splittedfiles/'):
    key = obj.key
    body = obj.get()['Body'].read()
```