# Reading a subset of csv files from S3 bucket using lambda and boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, prefix

In my s3 bucket I have around 30 csv files, classified into 3 categories. With my lambda I am interested to pick only 8 of them which belong to category 1.
I had used the response from the next question: [Reading multiple csv files from S3 bucket with boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52855221/reading-multiple-csv-files-from-s3-bucket-with-boto3)

so I formulated the next code:

```
def read_prefix_to_df(prefix,s3_resource,bucket_name):
    bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(bucket_name)
    prefix_objs = bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=prefix)
    prefix_df = []
    for obj in prefix_objs:
        key = obj.key
        body = obj.get()['Body'].read()
        df = pd.DataFrame(body)
        prefix_df.append(df)
    return prefix_df
```

Where :

```
bucket_name='my_bucket'
prefix='folder/data_overview_*.csv'
```

all the 8 files have almost the same name except the date at the end that's why I used the * to pick all files related to data_overview_
Unfortunately, the returned dataframe was empty, shall I change the prefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefixes cannot contain wildcard characters.

You should use:

```
prefix = 'folder/data_overview_`
```

If you need to further limit to only CSV files, then you will need to do that with an `if` statement within your Python code.