# Convert bytes csv string into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, parsing

I am pulling in a csv string and need to parse it into a pd dataframe. Example string:

```
b'date,"total revenue"\n2018-06-19,12.65\n2018-06-20,3.90\n2018-06-21,6.16\n2018-06-22,9.06\n2018-06-23,1.30\n2018-06-24,1.88\n2018-06-25,4.20\n2018-06-26,2.46\n2018-06-27,2.38\n2018-06-28,1.06\n`
```

How can I convert this string into a 2 column pandas dataframe? Many thanks

I tried the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(reader(str(my_string))))
```

But the output is all skewed:

```
                   0     1
0                  b  None
1                  '  None
2                  d  None
3                  a  None
4                  t  None
5                  e  None
6                         
7      total revenue  None
8                  \  None
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer here ([How to convert bytes data into a python pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47379476/how-to-convert-bytes-data-into-a-python-pandas-dataframe)):

```
from io import StringIO

s=str(bytes_data,'utf-8')

data = StringIO(s) 

df=pd.read_csv(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `io.BytesIO` instead of converting to string and using `io.StringIO` :
For example, retrieving CSV data from an API :

```
import io
import requests
r = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_logs")
data = io.BytesIO(r.content)
df = pd.read_csv(data)
```

(This is what Eric proposed above, but without the need to actually save the data to a persistent static file)

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
import pandas as pd

if sys.version_info[0] < 3: 
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO


temp =  StringIO(my_string)
df =pd.read_csv(temp, sep=",", lineterminator='\n')

df
```

You migth try this, and dont forget to remove b as it take rows for df as binary

Answer (score 1):

I use this way if the binary data is a csv file.

```
with open("test.csv", 'wb') as f:  
    f.write(bytes_data)
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
```