# Converting a Bytes object into a Pandas dataframe with Python3 results in an empty dataframe. Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, odoo, odoo-14

I was reading about Bytes libraries and Pandas and I think the answers in the following post should work for me:

[How to convert bytes data into a python pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47379476/how-to-convert-bytes-data-into-a-python-pandas-dataframe)

However, neither of them are working.

I have a CSV file with a few content. When I load it to Odoo, it returns the file into a `Bytes` object. I want to read this `Bytes` object with `pandas` and convert it into a `dataframe` in order to using `dataframe` methods.

The `Bytes` object comes in the attribute `file_to_import` of my class (that is why you'll see `self.file_to_import` in my code). If I show its type it returns `<class 'bytes'>`. If I decode it, I get its respective string:

> 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

It looks OK, so this should be enough:

```
from io import BytesIO
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(self.file_to_import))
```

However, `df` does not have any rows, and if I check `df.empty`, it returns `True`, so the `dataframe` does not have any info. If I check the size of the `BytesIO` object before trying to convert it into a `dataframe`, it returns 1376 bytes, which seems to be OK, since Dolphin shows a size of 1,0 KiB (1.031) for the file.

```
x = BytesIO(self.file_to_import)
_logger.critical(x.getbuffer().nbytes)
df = pd.read_csv(x))
```

Can anyone tell me why is this happening? Why the `dataframe` is empty?

Comment: It looks like a `base64` string. Maybe, you need to decode it before to use: `base64.decodebytes(s)`

Comment: @Corralien yes, that was the problem, I did not realize that fact... thank you very much! Convert your comment into an answer so I can set your answer as the right one.

Comment: Normally i would remove the odoo tags here, but odoo is converting files into base64, so i'm fine with the tags ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string is `base64` encoded. You need to decode it before to use:

```
import base64

s = b"ZGVmYXVsdF9jb2RlO2...Jhcm87Owo="
s = base64.decodebytes(s)
```