# How to convert string from df.to_string() back to DataFrame

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I know that DataFrame can be be converted to string using to_string function:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three'] * 3,
                   'B' : ['Aa', 'Bb', 'Cc'] * 4})
dfstr = df.to_string()
print(dfstr)
```

Output:

```
        A   B
0     one  Aa
1     one  Bb
2     two  Cc
3   three  Aa
4     one  Bb
5     one  Cc
6     two  Aa
7   three  Bb
8     one  Cc
9     one  Aa
10    two  Bb
11  three  Cc
```

How can I convert this `dfstr` back to a DataFrame object?

---

Edit:

I am asking specifically how the string created by `df.to_string()` function can be converted back to a dataframe object, not about general ways of converting text data (string) to dataframes as discussed on [How to create a Pandas DataFrame from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604564/how-to-create-a-pandas-dataframe-from-a-string) .

Comment: The `.to_csv()` method of pandas dataframes will return the would be contents of the csv file as a string if no file path is included as an argument. The returned string can be read with `io.StringIO()` and `pd.read_csv()` with no special arguments. I don't know why you want to use the `.to_string()` method, but in almost every circumstance in which you want to output a string that can later be read as a csv `.to_csv()` without a file path argument is the best option.

Comment: Looks very good suggestion. You should add this as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with `StringIO`:

```
from pandas.compat import StringIO #if this doesn't work try: from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(dfstr), sep='\s+')
print (df)

        A   B
0     one  Aa
1     one  Bb
2     two  Cc
3   three  Aa
4     one  Bb
5     one  Cc
6     two  Aa
7   three  Bb
8     one  Cc
9     one  Aa
10    two  Bb
11  three  Cc
```

Comment: Is there any reason not to close this as a duplicate of one of the many similar questions in the past?  The first one which I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604564/how-to-create-a-pandas-dataframe-from-a-string).

Comment: @DSM - so sorry, if think so, no problem if close question.