# gnupg - decrypt into Python bytesio stream

Tags: python, encryption, gnupg, bytesio

**How can I select a *stream* as the output of a `decrypt_file` operation in `gnupg`?**

The docs and the code seem to suggest this is not possible. If I am correct (see below), what workarounds are possible?

~~~

The **[documentation](https://python-gnupg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gnupg.html)** seems to suggest it is not possible:

```
decrypt_file(filename, always_trust=False, passphrase=None, output=None)¶
```

with *"**output (str)** – A filename to write the decrypted output to."*

~~~

Opening up the **code**, I see:

```
def decrypt_file(self, file, always_trust=False, passphrase=None,
                 output=None, extra_args=None):
    args = ["--decrypt"]
    if output:  # write the output to a file with the specified name
        self.set_output_without_confirmation(args, output)
    if always_trust:  # pragma: no cover
        args.append("--always-trust")
    if extra_args:
        args.extend(extra_args)
    result = self.result_map['crypt'](self)
    self._handle_io(args, file, result, passphrase, binary=True)
    logger.debug('decrypt result: %r', result.data)
    return result
```

which points to  `set_output_without_confirmation`, confirming the idea is that you pass a string filename:

```
def set_output_without_confirmation(self, args, output):
    "If writing to a file which exists, avoid a confirmation message."
    if os.path.exists(output):
        # We need to avoid an overwrite confirmation message
        args.extend(['--yes'])
    args.extend(['--output', no_quote(output)])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To output the decrypted data to a variable use `decrypt` instead of `decrypt_file`, as shown [here](https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2011/10/python-gnupg-gpg-example/) in the "**Decrypt a string**" paragraph.

So the original code:

```
status = gpg.decrypt_file(input_file, passphrase='my_passphrase', output='my_output_file')
```

is substituted by:

```
decrypted_data = gpg.decrypt(input_file.read(), passphrase='my_passphrase')
# decrypted_data.data contains the data
decrypted_stream = io.BytesIO(decrypted_data.data)
# this is py3, in py2 BytesIO is imported from BytesIO
```

As an example for the **specific use case for csv data**, building on this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604564/how-to-create-a-pandas-dataframe-from-a-string), you could then do:

```
my_df = pandas.read_csv(decrypted_stream)
```