# Is there a way to group users with their ip recursively?

Tags: pandas, pyspark

I want to group users with their IPs (or something else).
When IP(data)/user_id table is given such as in the below example, start with the user_id using the first data point (data = 1, users = (a,b,c)). Then gather other data values used by those users (users = (a,b,c), used_data = (2,4,5)). This continues until all users and data linked this way are discovered.

Example data (CSV, I substituted IP with random data to make it easier to read)

```
data,user_id
1,a
1,b
1,c
2,a
2,e
3,d
3,h
4,a
5,b
5,f
5,g
6,h
6,i
```

In short, i want to gather users who use the same data at least once.

Expected output in CSV,

```
group,data,user_id
1,[1,2,4,5],[a,b,c,e,f,g]
2,[3,6],[d,h,i]
```

Comment: I don't understand how exactly you are getting the output can you please elaborate?

Comment: I meant this
1. find users using specific ip
2. find ips used by the users in 1.
3. find users using the ips in 2.
4. repeatedly..
finally I want get groups of [(ips), (users)]

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be easier to do this out of pandas, with a little helper function. I've pasted your csv into a file to make it clear what the `data` variable contains. I've manually bypassed the header with indexing, it's up to you to automate this and remove the indices, as well as format the final result as a csv if needed. This solution is not explicitly recursive, but it's not (very) wasteful either.

```
with open('test.csv') as infile:
    data = [l.strip().split(',') for l in infile.readlines()]

def extract_group(data):
    # Start with one entry
    ip, user = data[0]
    ips = {ip}
    users = {user}
    ungrouped = data[1:]
    old_ungrouped_count = 0
    # Go through the remaining data until no related entries are found
    while len(ungrouped) != old_ungrouped_count:
        old_ungrouped_count = len(ungrouped)
        for ip, user in ungrouped[:]:
            if ip in ips or user in users:
                ips.add(ip)
                users.add(user)
                ungrouped.remove([ip, user])
    return (users, ips, ungrouped)

users, ips, ungrouped = extract_group(data[1:])
groups = [(sorted(ips), sorted(users))]
while ungrouped:
    users, ips, ungrouped = extract_group(ungrouped)
    groups.append((sorted(ips), sorted(users)))

for group in groups:
    print(group)

(['1', '2', '4', '5'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g'])
(['3', '6'], ['d', 'h', 'i'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` method, you can find the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). You can do it with SQL query if you want to, with using `group_concat()` or a substitute for it. For further reading look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604564/create-pandas-dataframe-from-a-string) post.

**Code**

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

raw_data = """data,user_id
1,a
1,b
1,c
2,a
2,e
3,d
3,h
4,a
5,b
5,f
5,g
6,h
6,i"""


df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(raw_data), sep=',')
grouped_df = df.groupby(['data']).apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.user_id))
```

**Output**

```
data
1    a,b,c
2      a,e
3      d,h
4        a
5    b,f,g
6      h,i
dtype: object
```