# Upload csv for processing in PyScript

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, pyscript

The following is my failed attempt at writing HTML/Javascript/PyScript code that allows a user to upload a csv (or excel) file, which is then available for use in PyScript (e.g., Pandas). As you might notice, I am not very experienced with Javascript.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
        
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
    
    <py-config>
        packages = ["pandas"]
    </py-config>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="file" id="fileinput" accept=".csv, .xlsx"/>

    <script>
        var test = "test";

        function assignFile(e) {
            // Assign file to js variable
            window.file = e.target.files[0];
            console.log("File assigned")
        }
    </script>

    <py-script>
import pandas as pd
import js
import pyodide
from js import test
js.console.log(test)

def get_file(e):
    js.console.log("Attempting file upload: " + e.target.value)

    # Assign file to a js variable
    js.assignFile(e)
    # Import variable to python
    from js import file

    display(pd.read_csv(file))

get_file_proxy = pyodide.ffi.create_proxy(get_file)

js.document.getElementById("fileinput").addEventListener("change", get_file_proxy)
    </py-script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Some notes to this code: I am aware that the part written in the `script` element could also be written in the `py-script` element, but decided not to. Furthermore, the line `from js import file` [imports the variable created in Javascript](https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/guides/passing-objects.html#javascript-to-pyscript), but when I try to use this variable with Pandas, it gives me the error in the console `Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'pyodide.JsProxy'>`. This is contrary to the properly functioning line `from js import test`. However, the specific error is unimportant to my question, which is:

What would be a simple way to allow a user to upload a csv (or xlsx) file for use in PyScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to use the `event.target.files` attribute of the `FileEvent`. This can be read using the common async JavaScript methods, like `.text()` or `.arrayBuffer()`. To read a CSV file from text with pandas [you need to use an in-memory stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58288236/pandas-read-csv-stored-as-string-in-memory-to-data-frame), like `io.StringIO` or `io.BytesIO`.

I adapted your PyScript code like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import pyodide
import io
import js

async def get_file(e):
    files = e.target.files.to_py()
    for file in files:
      file_content = await file.text()
      df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(file_content))
      js.console.log(df)

get_file_proxy = pyodide.ffi.create_proxy(get_file)

js.document.getElementById("fileinput").addEventListener("change", get_file_proxy)
```

Keep in mind, that large files might be better read using a buffer, but I do not exactly know best practices for this in PyScript.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. It works beautifully and is much better understandable than some other tutorials out there.