# Why is pandas.read_fwf not skipping the blank line as instructed?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, io, fixed-width

I'm reading a fixed width format ([full source file](ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/isd-history.txt)) full of missing data, so `pandas.read_fwf` comes in handy.  There is an empty line after the header, so I'm passing `skip_blank_lines=True`, but this appears to have no effect, as the first entry is still full of NaN/NaT:

```py
import io
import pandas

s="""USAF   WBAN  STATION NAME                  CTRY ST CALL  LAT     LON      ELEV(M) BEGIN    END

007018 99999 WXPOD 7018                                  +00.000 +000.000 +7018.0 20110309 20130730
007026 99999 WXPOD 7026                    AF            +00.000 +000.000 +7026.0 20120713 20170822
007070 99999 WXPOD 7070                    AF            +00.000 +000.000 +7070.0 20140923 20150926
008260 99999 WXPOD8270                                   +00.000 +000.000 +0000.0 20050101 20100920
008268 99999 WXPOD8278                     AF            +32.950 +065.567 +1156.7 20100519 20120323
008307 99999 WXPOD 8318                    AF            +00.000 +000.000 +8318.0 20100421 20100421
008411 99999 XM20                                                                 20160217 20160217
008414 99999 XM18                                                                 20160216 20160217
008415 99999 XM21                                                                 20160217 20160217
008418 99999 XM24                                                                 20160217 20160217
010000 99999 BOGUS NORWAY                  NO      ENRS                           20010927 20041019
010010 99999 JAN MAYEN(NOR-NAVY)           NO      ENJA  +70.933 -008.667 +0009.0 19310101 20200111
010013 99999 ROST                          NO                                     19861120 19880105
010014 99999 SORSTOKKEN                    NO      ENSO  +59.792 +005.341 +0048.8 19861120 20200110
"""

print(pandas.read_fwf(io.StringIO(s), parse_dates=["BEGIN", "END"],
      skip_blank_lines=True))
```

Which results in:

```
USAF     WBAN         STATION NAME  ... ELEV(M)      BEGIN        END
0       NaN      NaN                  NaN  ...     NaN        NaT        NaT
1    7018.0  99999.0           WXPOD 7018  ...  7018.0 2011-03-09 2013-07-30
2    7026.0  99999.0           WXPOD 7026  ...  7026.0 2012-07-13 2017-08-22
3    7070.0  99999.0           WXPOD 7070  ...  7070.0 2014-09-23 2015-09-26
4    8260.0  99999.0            WXPOD8270  ...     0.0 2005-01-01 2010-09-20
5    8268.0  99999.0            WXPOD8278  ...  1156.7 2010-05-19 2012-03-23
6    8307.0  99999.0           WXPOD 8318  ...  8318.0 2010-04-21 2010-04-21
7    8411.0  99999.0                 XM20  ...     NaN 2016-02-17 2016-02-17
8    8414.0  99999.0                 XM18  ...     NaN 2016-02-16 2016-02-17
9    8415.0  99999.0                 XM21  ...     NaN 2016-02-17 2016-02-17
10   8418.0  99999.0                 XM24  ...     NaN 2016-02-17 2016-02-17
11  10000.0  99999.0         BOGUS NORWAY  ...     NaN 2001-09-27 2004-10-19
12  10010.0  99999.0  JAN MAYEN(NOR-NAVY)  ...     9.0 1931-01-01 2020-01-11
13  10013.0  99999.0                 ROST  ...     NaN 1986-11-20 1988-01-05
14  10014.0  99999.0           SORSTOKKEN  ...    48.8 1986-11-20 2020-01-10

[15 rows x 11 columns]
```

Row 0 still has values for all columns.  I was expecting row 0 to be the first non-empty data row, starting with 007018.  Why does `skip_blank_lines=True` appear to have no effect?  How can I tell pandas to skip the blank line?  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One missing detail in your code is that you failed to pass *widths* parameter.

But this is not all.
Another problem is that unfortunately, *read_fwf* contains such a bug that it
**ignores** *skip_blank_lines* parameter.

To cope with it, define the following class, containing *readline* method
skipping empty lines:

```
class LineFilter(io.TextIOBase):
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.iterable = iterable

    def readline(self):
        while True:
            line = next(self.iterable).strip()
            if line:
                return line
```

Then run:

```
df = pd.read_fwf(LineFilter(io.StringIO(s)), widths=[7, 6, 30, 8, 6, 8, 9, 8, 9, 9],
    parse_dates=["BEGIN", "END"], na_filter=False)
```

As you can see, I added *na_filter=False* to block conversion of
empty strings to *NaN* values.

Comment: The widths parameter is optional, `read_fwf` can automatically determine it from the file contents.

Comment: I just noticed [this was reported as an issue on 2018-09-13](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/22693).

Answer (score -1):

If there is one colum which will surly have some value, if you remove blank line for that colum , that may work..

Try below

```
df.dropna(subset=['WBAN'], how='all', inplace=True)
print(df.head())
```

Comment: You've misunderstood my question.  I'm looking to skip empty *rows*, not empty columns.

Comment: my line is not to drop the column but the row only, if given column has blank or NaN value that row will be deleted, you misunderstood the approach

Comment: I don't want to drop lines where some columns have missing values, I want to drop lines that are completely blank in the source file.