# Parse list and create DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have been given a list called data which has the following content

```
data=[b'Name,Age,Occupation,Salary\r\nRam,37,Plumber,1769\r\nMohan,49,Elecrician,3974\r\nRahim,39,Teacher,4559\r\n']
```

I wanted to have a pandas dataframe which looks like the link
[Expected Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hjsc.png)

How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
data=[b'Name,Age,Occupation,Salary\r\nRam,37,Plumber,1769\r\nMohan,49,Elecrician,3974\r\nRahim,39,Teacher,4559\r\n']

processed_data = [x.split(',') for x in data[0].decode().replace('\r', '').strip().split('\n')]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=processed_data[0], data=processed_data[1:])
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks This worked perfectly. Will it have any performance issue if used over a large data? This example was a simple one. Actual use case may have millions of records.

Comment: I think it should be fine (may take a few seconds at max). List comprehensions in python are very fast. But let me know if it slows down too much.

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to convert this list to string as there is only one index in this list

```
str1 = ''.join(data)
```

Then use solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604564/create-pandas-dataframe-from-a-string)

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3: 
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd

TESTDATA = StringIO(str1)
df = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, sep=",")
```