# unable to read head after converting excel to csv

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, data-science

I am trying to read an excel file, convert it into csv and load its head:

```
df = pd.read_excel("final.xlsx", sheet_name="NewCustomerList")
# df = df.to_csv()
print(df.head(3))
```

Without converting to csv, the results look like this:

```
  Note: The data and information in this document is reflective of a hypothetical situation and client.  \
0                                         first_name                                                                                                                              
1                                            Chickie                                                                                                                              
2                                              Morly
```

However, if I uncomment the conversion, I get an error that:

```
'str' object has no attribute 'head'
```

I am guessing its because of the first line of the data. How else can I convert this properly and read it?

Comment: In the docs, to_csv returns None or a string. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Answer (score 2):

[to_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) is used to save a table to disk, it has no effect on memory-stored tables and returns None. So, you are changing your df variable to None with your commented line.

If you just want to display the table on screen in a specific format, perhaps take a look at [to_string()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html)

If you absolutely MUST have each row of your df as a comma-separated string then try a list comprehension:

```
my_csv_list = [','.join(map(str, row)) for row in df.itertuples()]
```

Beware of the csv format, if any datapoint contains a comma then you are in for a nightmare when decoding back to a table.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html), Pandas' `to_csv()` method returns None (nothing) or a string.

You could further need to use something like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604564/create-pandas-dataframe-from-a-string#22605281) to turn the string into a dataframe again and use its head.