# Is there a possibility to describe how frequent "Rood" occurs over the different years/months?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, group-by, frequency-analysis

I tried to first group the different dates with the function groupby. I want to group the dates by months for the different years. In a month, I want to find visualize how many times a an order is "Rood", as shown in the picture. How can i do this?

[image: picture of data at this moment]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). "Implement this feature for me" is off-topic for this site. You have to make an honest attempt, and then ask a specific question about your algorithm or technique.

Comment: Hi Juul, to prepare the question better you can do the following: 1. reduce your excel to just 3-5 lines and remove some columns keep just 2-3 to give us idea. Save it to csv so that you can give it to us as pure text in the question. 2. post your code as formatted code. Here is example https://stackoverflow.com/a/22605281/678491 .

Comment: How do you want to visualize the result? Should it be a list of tuples, or a  barchart? Please exemplify or provide the specs of the chart.