# Tab separated data into a DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have an API call that is returning tab-separated data using python. I can export and then load using `pd.read_csv("FileName.txt", sep="\t")` however I was looking to take the data from the call and then load it straight into a Dataframe (without having to save it and use read_csv). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: what is the type of data you return? you can wrap a `StringIO` and read the StringIO object with read_csv. Or there might be a better way depending on how your data gets returned. look at this: [Create Pandas DataFrame from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604564/create-pandas-dataframe-from-a-string)

Comment: StringIO worked perfectly thank you

Comment: thanks for confirming, closing the question since this has been asked before.