# Pandas apply row-wise a function and create multiple new columns

Tags: python, pandas, apply

What is the best way to apply a row-wise function and create multiple new columns?

I have two dataframes and a working code, but it's most likely not optimal

df1 (dataframe has thousands of rows and xx number of columns)

| sic | data1 | data2 | data3 | data4 | data5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 0.90783598 | 0.84722083 | 0.47149924 | 0.98724123 | 0.50654476 |
| 6 | 0.53442684 | 0.59730371 | 0.92486887 | 0.61531646 | 0.62784041 |
| 3 | 0.56806423 | 0.09619383 | 0.33846097 | 0.71878313 | 0.96316724 |
| 8 | 0.86933042 | 0.64965755 | 0.94549745 | 0.08866519 | 0.92156389 |
| 12 | 0.651328 | 0.37193774 | 0.9679044 | 0.36898991 | 0.15161838 |
| 6 | 0.24555531 | 0.50195983 | 0.79114578 | 0.9290596 | 0.10672607 |

df2 (column header maps to the sic-code in df1. There are in total 12 sic-codes and the dataframe is thousands of rows long)

|  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| c_bar | 0.4955329 | 0.92970292 | 0.68049726 | 0.91325006 | 0.55578465 | 0.78056519 | 0.53954711 | 0.90335326 | 0.93986402 | 0.0204794 | 0.51575764 | 0.61144255 |
| a1_bar | 0.75781444 | 0.81052669 | 0.99910449 | 0.62181902 | 0.11797144 | 0.40031316 | 0.08561665 | 0.35296894 | 0.14445697 | 0.93799762 | 0.80641802 | 0.31379671 |
| a2_bar | 0.41432552 | 0.36313911 | 0.13091618 | 0.39251953 | 0.66249636 | 0.31221897 | 0.15988528 | 0.1620938 | 0.55143589 | 0.66571044 | 0.68198944 | 0.23806947 |
| a3_bar | 0.38918855 | 0.83689178 | 0.15838139 | 0.39943204 | 0.48615188 | 0.06299899 | 0.86343819 | 0.47975619 | 0.05300611 | 0.15080875 | 0.73088725 | 0.3500239 |
| a4_bar | 0.47201384 | 0.90874121 | 0.50417142 | 0.70047698 | 0.24820601 | 0.34302454 | 0.4650635 | 0.0992668 | 0.55142391 | 0.82947194 | 0.28251699 | 0.53170308 |

I achieved the result I need with the following code:

```
ind_list = np.arange(1,13) # Create list of industries 


def c_bar(row):
    for i in ind_list:
        if row['sic'] == i:
            return mlev_mean.loc['const',i]


def a1_bar(row):
    for i in ind_list:
        if row['sic'] == i:
            return mlev_mean.loc['a1bar',i]


def a2_bar(row):
    for i in ind_list:
        if row['sic'] == i:
            return mlev_mean.loc['a2bar',i]


def a3_bar(row):
    for i in ind_list:
        if row['sic'] == i:
            return mlev_mean.loc['a3bar',i]


def a4_bar(row):
    for i in ind_list:
        if row['sic'] == i:
            return mlev_mean.loc['a4bar',i]
            
mlev_merge['c_bar'] = mlev_merge.apply(c_bar, axis=1, result_type='expand')        
mlev_merge['a1_bar'] = mlev_merge.apply(a1_bar, axis=1, result_type='expand')
mlev_merge['a2_bar'] = mlev_merge.apply(a2_bar, axis=1, result_type='expand')
mlev_merge['a3_bar'] = mlev_merge.apply(a3_bar, axis=1, result_type='expand')
mlev_merge['a4_bar'] = mlev_merge.apply(a4_bar, axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

The output is something like this:

| sic | data1 | data2 | data3 | data4 | c_bar | a1_bar | a2_bar | a3_bar | a4_bar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 0.10316948 | 0.61408639 | 0.04042675 | 0.79255749 | 0.56357931 | 0.42920472 | 0.20701581 | 0.67639811 | 0.37778029 |
| 6 | 0.5730904 | 0.16753145 | 0.27835136 | 0.00178992 | 0.51793793 | 0.06772307 | 0.15084885 | 0.12451806 | 0.33114948 |
| 3 | 0.87710893 | 0.66834187 | 0.14286608 | 0.12609769 | 0.75873957 | 0.72586804 | 0.6081763 | 0.14598001 | 0.21557266 |
| 8 | 0.24565579 | 0.56195558 | 0.93316676 | 0.20988936 | 0.67404545 | 0.65221594 | 0.79758557 | 0.67093021 | 0.33400764 |
| 12 | 0.79703344 | 0.61066111 | 0.94602909 | 0.56218703 | 0.92384307 | 0.30836159 | 0.72521994 | 0.00795362 | 0.76348227 |
| 6 | 0.86604791 | 0.28454782 | 0.97229172 | 0.21853932 | 0.75650652 | 0.40788056 | 0.53233553 | 0.60326386 | 0.27399405 |

Cell values in the example are randomly generated, but the point is to map based on sic-codes and add rows from df2 as new columns into df1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you need to:

1. Transpose `df2` so that its columns are correct for concatenation
2. Index it with the `df1["sic"]` column to get the correct rows
3. Reset the index of the obtained rows of `df2` using `.reset_index(drop=True)`, so that the dataframes can be concatenated correctly. (This replaces the current index e.g. `5, 6, 3, 8, 12, 6` with a new one e.g. `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5` while keeping the actual values the same. This is so that pandas doesn't get confused while concatenating them)
4. Concatenate the two dataframes

Note: I used [a method based off of this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22605281/16768672) to read in the dataframe, and it assumed that the columns of `df2` were strings but the values of the `sic` column of `df1` were ints. Therefore I used `.astype(str)` to get step 2 working. If this is not actually the case, you may need to remove the `.astype(str)`.

Here is the single line of code to do these things:

```py
merged = pd.concat([df1, df2.T.loc[df1["sic"].astype(str)].reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
```

Here is the full code I used:

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
sic data1   data2   data3   data4   data5
5   0.90783598  0.84722083  0.47149924  0.98724123  0.50654476
6   0.53442684  0.59730371  0.92486887  0.61531646  0.62784041
3   0.56806423  0.09619383  0.33846097  0.71878313  0.96316724
8   0.86933042  0.64965755  0.94549745  0.08866519  0.92156389
12  0.651328    0.37193774  0.9679044   0.36898991  0.15161838
6   0.24555531  0.50195983  0.79114578  0.9290596   0.10672607
"""), sep="\t")
df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
c_bar   0.4955329   0.92970292  0.68049726  0.91325006  0.55578465  0.78056519  0.53954711  0.90335326  0.93986402  0.0204794   0.51575764  0.61144255
a1_bar  0.75781444  0.81052669  0.99910449  0.62181902  0.11797144  0.40031316  0.08561665  0.35296894  0.14445697  0.93799762  0.80641802  0.31379671
a2_bar  0.41432552  0.36313911  0.13091618  0.39251953  0.66249636  0.31221897  0.15988528  0.1620938   0.55143589  0.66571044  0.68198944  0.23806947
a3_bar  0.38918855  0.83689178  0.15838139  0.39943204  0.48615188  0.06299899  0.86343819  0.47975619  0.05300611  0.15080875  0.73088725  0.3500239
a4_bar  0.47201384  0.90874121  0.50417142  0.70047698  0.24820601  0.34302454  0.4650635   0.0992668   0.55142391  0.82947194  0.28251699  0.53170308
"""), sep="\t", index_col=[0])

merged = pd.concat([df1, df2.T.loc[df1["sic"].astype(str)].reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)

print(merged)
```

which produces the output:

```
   sic     data1     data2     data3  ...    a1_bar    a2_bar    a3_bar    a4_bar
0    5  0.907836  0.847221  0.471499  ...  0.117971  0.662496  0.486152  0.248206
1    6  0.534427  0.597304  0.924869  ...  0.400313  0.312219  0.062999  0.343025
2    3  0.568064  0.096194  0.338461  ...  0.999104  0.130916  0.158381  0.504171
3    8  0.869330  0.649658  0.945497  ...  0.352969  0.162094  0.479756  0.099267
4   12  0.651328  0.371938  0.967904  ...  0.313797  0.238069  0.350024  0.531703
5    6  0.245555  0.501960  0.791146  ...  0.400313  0.312219  0.062999  0.343025

[6 rows x 11 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try transposing df2 and applying transformations to it.
Transposing a data frame means converting the rows into columns of your data frame.

`df2_tr = df2.T.map(lambda col:mapFunc(col),axis=0)`

then, you can use concatenate the transformed columns of df2 with the columns of df1, using `df1 = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)`.