# Where to find plotly example data?

Tags: python, plotly

I just wanted to follow [this plotly tutorial](https://blog.resolvingpython.com/04-data-visualization-in-python) in which the author seem to use some test data. But in the article it does not say where I can get that test data from.

Also the [plotly documentation](https://plotly.com/python/animations/) does not seem so.

I tried to comment on the article which also did not work as this "hashnode" thing does not seem to work at all. I kind of cannot log in or something, and I cannot contact their customer support.

So if anyone knows how to obtain the test data that would be great. Please feel free to suggest some other forum for this question.

Comment: Seems like a documentation request better suited for an issue on the [Plotly GitHub](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues) page? In general if it is some random blog post you are at the mercy of the post's author to provide a fully self-contained example including necessary data.

Comment: ah plotly github. Yes did not think of that, and never saw it. Thanks

Comment: First cell in the tutorial is ``df_countries = px.data.gapminder()``. Isn't that your data ?

Comment: I do not get any output. I thought so first. Maybe I am doing something wrong? Need to install something extra?

Comment: Ah the tutorial IS incorrect. There is an error. It should be `print(df_countries).

Comment: But there is no graphical output. That is ALSO missing

Comment: See also [https://github.com/plotly/datasets](https://github.com/plotly/datasets) and [plotly.data package](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.data.html).

Comment: The referenced site is described on a cell-by-cell basis under the premise of jupyter notebook and jupyterlab. References can be made by data frame name only.

Comment: If that would work. If that would work. Started the very first example in jupyter lab, but either that first 3-line example takes more than 5 minutes(!) to complete, or I am still missing something...

Comment: Wow it really took about 5 minutes to complete. Wow. `plotly` does not seem to belong in the `performant` packages, does it?

Answer (score 0):

The article says:

> Look at the following example as an aspiration you can achieve if you
> fully understand and replicate this whole tutorial with your data.

So the idea is to use any [pandas.Dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) of your choice, you can [type your own from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604564/create-pandas-dataframe-from-a-string) or take one from the internet, like the ones you can find on [this](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/%7Ejburkardt/data/csv/csv.html) website and open them with the following lines:

```
import pandas as pd

url: str = 'https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/oscar_age_male.csv'
df: pd.DataFrame = pd.read_csv(url)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have `plotly` installed, `px.data` is included in the package, so everyone can easily utilize the datasets to plot.

```
import plotly.express as px
df_countries = px.data.gapminder()
print(df_countries.head(10))
###
```

[image]

And it won't take you long,

```
%timeit df_countries = px.data.gapminder()
4.89 ms ± 181 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```