# How to dataframe the following string with headers?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following string from a text file:

```
'Statement of Account,09 OCT AMAZON PRIME 38.87,09 OCT FP*FOOD CART 37.09,20 SEP MTHLY CASHBACK - VISA PAYW 5.96 CR'
```

How do dataframe the string output as follow:

| Date | Description | Amount | Remarks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 09 Oct | AMAZON PRIME | 38.87 |  |
| ... | ... | ... |  |
| 20 SEP | MTHLY CASHBACK - VISA PAYW | 5.96 | CR |

Comment: What about [ask]? What have you tried or researched?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create Pandas DataFrame from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604564/create-pandas-dataframe-from-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this simple format and no escaped commas, you could [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the string on `,` to form a Series, then use a regex with [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to get each part as an individual column:

```
text = 'Statement of Account,09 OCT AMAZON PRIME 38.87,09 OCT FP*FOOD CART 37.09,20 SEP MTHLY CASHBACK - VISA PAYW 5.96 CR'

l = text.split(',')
s = pd.Series(l[1:], name=l[0])
df = s.str.extract('^(?P<Date>\d+ [A-Z]+) (?P<Description>.+?) (?P<Amount>\d+\.?\d*)(?: (?P<Remarks>[A-Z]+))?$')
```

Output:

```
     Date                 Description Amount Remarks
0  09 OCT                AMAZON PRIME  38.87     NaN
1  09 OCT                FP*FOOD CART  37.09     NaN
2  20 SEP  MTHLY CASHBACK - VISA PAYW   5.96      CR
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xRRUIW/1)